# Push-ups form and progression

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, push-ups

I am a 15 year old boy.

Height: 5 feet 6 inches.

Weight: 61kg.

I am unable to do push-ups properly. I can do up to 8 knee push-ups. However after that I can't keep my shoulders in their place and they come up.

I can't do even one complete push-up.

What can I do to do complete pushups? Please suggest some progressions. I have been doing knee push-ups for about 2 months now. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You should keep doing knee pushups, but you should also start doing regular pushups at an incline.

[image]

Find an angle where you can do 10-15 repetitions. If you can do more than that, find something lower. With time, you'll be coming down onto the ground, doing regular pushups!

Comment: reddit's /r/bodyweightfitness has some good progressions and guides: https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/playground/pushup

Comment: also practice planking in the upper positon

Answer (score -3):

Lowering about 1/3 to 1/2 way done and HOLDING there
will help you build the strength to do the full depth.

I lost ALL strength from illness - was in the same predicament
and this is how I recovered.